# NSIS execwait will not launch any network located exe, using a variable (execwait '$PATHTOEXE' )

Tags: nsis

My code for a NSIS execwait will not launch any network located exe, using a variable (`execwait '$PATHTOEXE'`) even though it contains the full path to the exe.

Yes, the variable contains the correct path and syntax for a path, along with the correct name of the exe. The user has full administrator (full control) rights to the folder/exe on the network.

The exe launches immediately when the execwait has the full path i.e. `execwait 'P:\folder\folder\setup.exe'`. It does not launch the app with `execwait '$PATHTOEXE'` - the best I've gotten on occasion is the msiexec command line msg box to pop up.

I've used a msg box to make sure the global variable contains the correct path (e.g. `P:\folder\folder\setup.exe`) which is identical to the typed path that works.

Yes I have tried adding double quotes '"$PATHTOEXE"'. I have tried adding the `execwait 'msiexec /i $PATHTOEXE'` with and without double quotes. I have tried making the variable just to the root directory and adding the setup.exe to the line (i.e. `execwait '$PATHTOEXE\setup.exe'`) with and without double quotes. The particular setup.exe was created by install shield.

Anyone have an idea of what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: So P: is a mapped drive?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which path it tries to execute when it fails...

Comment: Yes a mapped drive to the location of the executable.